# where statement doesn't work correctly in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am using MYSQL in my c# app.

There are some string values in mysql table and there is a textbox that client can write in  that and then I use this statement to show the results:

```
"SELECT ID,METER FROM DB.TABLE1 WHERE METER >= '" +TEXT1.text.tostring+"'";
```

But for Example, if the client write 400 in that textbox, the results are like this:

```
50,400,500,600,50,500
```

But we know that 50 is not bigger than 400!!!
And then I used this code:

```
"SELECT ID,METER FROM DB.TABLE1 WHERE METER <= '" +TEXT1.text.tostring+"'";
```

If the client write 400 in that textbox, the results are like this:

```
300,150,100,250;
```

50 is not shown!!!

Can you please help me what should I do???

Comment: You should NEVER concatenate SQL queries, use parameters

Comment: I belive, that METER datatype is VARCHAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50 is "bigger" than 400 when you treat them as *strings*, so I suspect that's what you're doing.

First: never, never, never build SQL like this. It's susceptible to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), it leads to error-prone conversions, and it makes your code harder to read.

Instead, use parameterized SQL. In this case you'll want SQL of something like:

```
SELECT ID,METER FROM DB.TABLE1 WHERE METER >= @Parameter
```

and then set the `@Parameter` parameter in the parameter collection - parsing it as an integer (or whatever type is suitable for the values you're trying to represent) first.

Next: check the type of `METER` in your schema. If it's `varchar` or some similar text type, you need to fix that. It should be a suitable *numeric* type if you want to treat the values as numbers.

Comment: thanks for your answer.But I'm not familiar with this type of build.  can you give me a link for this type of sql.  thanks

Comment: @Massoud: So I suggest you find out about it :) For example, read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

< and > operator will work perfeclty on numeric values as you have added single quotes to the values you have passed, it may be causing the issue. try this

```
"SELECT ID,METER FROM DB.TABLE1 WHERE METER >= "+TEXT1.text.tostring;
```

Comment: Are you fond of SQL injection attacks? *Please* don't suggest code like this... even though SQL injection isn't the issue at hand, we should stamp it out *every chance we get*.

Comment: No, not like that, actually parametrized way should be the perfect one. I just have suggested the easiest solution.

Comment: And in doing so, left the OP vulnerable to SQL injection attack. You've basically encouraged the OP to leave a huge hole in their SQL - why do that rather than suggesting using parameterized SQL? If the OP finds that this solution works for them right now, they may well keep going with this *bad, bad* code - rather than fixing a major problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will consider suggesting the parametrized query solution next time.

Answer (score 0):

Convert user input to Integer and then use the integer value in your query.

```
SELECT ID,METER FROM DB.TABLE1 WHERE METER >= Convert.ToInteger(TEXT1.text.ToString()) ;
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I think It's because the values are string.

Answer (score 0):

Text comparison isn't numeric comparison. To avoid this misleading behavior and sql injection risk you must use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a string to a number in MySQL:

`var sql = @"
   SELECT ID, METER 
     FROM DB.TABLE1 
    WHERE CAST(METER AS UNSIGNED) >= "
  + Convert.ToInteger(TEXT1.text.ToString());`

There are all kinds of oddities to consider when dealing with numbers as strings in MySQL.

I suggest reading: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

As Jon has suggested, a better solution would be to ALTER the table schema to use a numeric column datatype and use SQL parameters in your code, especially as you seem to be dealing with user input.